# quickfix/n error:'An Existing was forcibly closed the remote host at Quickfix.SocketInitiatorThread.Read()'

Tags: c#, quickfix, fix-protocol

I have created a Fix application using `QuickFIX/n is v1.4.0` from this http://www.quickfixn.org/download site.
When I executed an application using two Pcs one as Server and Client, it gave an error:

> An Existing was forcibly closed the remote host at
>   `Quickfix.SocketInitiatorThread.Read()`

And Log details are:

```
20130814-23:23:47.828 : Created session
20130814-23:24:07.531 : FIX.4.4:Server->Client Socket Reader 6044116 accepting session FIX.4.4:Server->Client from 192.168.1.109:3300
20130814-23:24:07.531 : FIX.4.4:Server->Client Acceptor heartbeat set to 0 seconds
20130814-23:24:07.781 : Session reset: ResetOnLogon
20130814-23:24:07.796 : Sending time accuracy problem
20130814-23:24:07.812 : Message 1 Rejected: 10
20130814-23:24:07.812 : Verify failed: Tried to send a reject while not logged on
20130814-23:24:07.812 : Session FIX.4.4:Server->Client disconnecting: Verify failed: Tried to send a reject while not logged on
20130814-23:24:07.812 : Session reset: ResetOnDisconnect
```

We have tried for 'Sending time accuracy problem' i.e. Timestamp error. We set the time on client and server machines same and tried it but it didn't work.
We also set the values of `MaxLatency` and `CheckLatency` in config file. We set `MaxLatency=120` and `CheckLatency=Y` but it didn't solve the problem.Please can you give me solution for this issue.

The actual log messages are:

```
20130816-05:44:37.875 : 8=FIX.4.49=6735=A34=149=Client52=20130816-23:12:39.56256=Server98=0108=3010=223
20130816-05:44:39.437 : 8=FIX.4.49=6735=A34=349=Client52=20130816-23:12:41.40656=Server98=0108=3010=215
20130816-05:44:40.468 : 8=FIX.4.49=6735=A34=449=Client52=20130816-23:12:42.40656=Server98=0108=3010=217
20130816-06:46:02.843 : 8=FIX.4.49=7335=A34=149=Client52=20130817-00:13:43.04656=Server98=0108=30141=Y10=254
20130816-06:46:04.515 : 8=FIX.4.49=7335=A34=149=Client52=20130817-00:13:45.89056=Server98=0108=30141=Y10=007
20130816-06:46:05.515 : 8=FIX.4.49=7335=A34=149=Client52=20130817-00:13:46.89056=Server98=0108=30141=Y10=008
20130816-06:46:10.359 : 8=FIX.4.49=7335=A34=149=Client52=20130817-00:13:51.62556=Server98=0108=30141=Y10=000
```

Please kindly send me suggestions and settings to run this application without errors.

Comment: Can you include the actual FIX messages being exchanged?

Comment: Have you tried `CheckLatency=N`?

Comment: yes.we checked for different values.nothing worked.

Comment: May be worth including the config. you're using for both client and server in the question.

Comment: client side config file is [DEFAULT]
FileStorePath=store
FileLogPath=log
ConnectionType=initiator
ReconnectInterval=60
SenderCompID=Client

[SESSION]
BeginString=FIX.4.4
TargetCompID=Executor
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
HeartBtInt=30 
SocketConnectPort=5001
SocketConnectHost=192.168.1.109
DataDictionary=FIX44.xml
UseDataDictionary=Y
#HttpAcceptPort=9911
LogoutTimeout=5
ResetOnLogon=Y

Comment: Sever side config file is [DEFAULT]
FileStorePath=store
FileLogPath=log
ConnectionType=acceptor
ReconnectInterval=60
SenderCompID=Executor

[SESSION]
BeginString=FIX.4.4 
TargetCompID=Client
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
HeartBtInt=30
SocketAcceptPort=5001
DataDictionary=FIX44.xml
SocketAcceptHost=192.168.1.2
SocketReuseAddress=Y
UseDataDictionary=Y
ResetOnLogon=Y
ResetOnLogout=Y
ResetOnDisconnect=Y

Comment: Have you changed the config since posting the logs and FIX messages? The logs suggest your CompIDs are `Client` and `Server`, but your config suggests that the CompIDs are `Client` and `Executor`.

Comment: we did make changes as you say. acceptor's config file is:- [DEFAULT]
HeartBtInt=30
ConnectionType=acceptor
SocketAcceptPort=5001
SocketReuseAddress=Y
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
FileLogPath=log
UseDataDictionary=Y
ResetOnLogon=Y
ResetOnLogout=Y
ResetOnDisconnect=Y

[SESSION]
BeginString=FIX.4.4
SenderCompID=Server 
TargetCompID=Client
FileStorePath=store
DataDictionary=FIX44.xml

Comment: initiators/clients config file is :- [DEFAULT]
HeartBtInt=30 
ConnectionType=initiator
ReconnectInterval=1
FileStorePath=store
FileLogPath=log
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
UseDataDictionary=Y
DataDictionary=FIX44.xml
HttpAcceptPort=9911
SocketConnectPort=5001
LogoutTimeout=5
ResetOnLogon=Y

[SESSION]
BeginString=FIX.4.4
SenderCompID=Client
TargetCompID=Server
SocketConnectHost=192.168.1.109

Comment: possible duplicate of [quickfix/n : Connection forcibly closed by remote host at Quickfix.SocketInitiatorThread.Read()'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224902/quickfix-n-connection-forcibly-closed-by-remote-host-at-quickfix-socketinitiat)

Comment: That question had been removed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like someone else answered your [identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224902/quickfix-n-connection-forcibly-closed-by-remote-host-at-quickfix-socketinitiat) 2 days ago, correctly identifying that the `CheckLatency` setting is, for whatever reason hard-coded in QuickFIX/n. In other words, it does not matter whether `CheckLatency=Y` or `CheckLatency=N` in your configuration file because it will be ignored when the configuration is loaded.

Again, as the other poster indicated, you can fix this in the QuickFIX/n source and rebuild the assembly.

The other option here is to change the `Session`'s `CheckLatency` property to false in your code before the connection is initiated.

Comment: Actually that solution didn't solve the problem.checked for time stamp error also.but it didn't work.Any other solution??

Comment: If the logs still indicate `Sending time accuracy problem` then that *is* the problem. Your solutions are therefore to fix the clock synchronisation/time-zones on your server/client, or tell QuickFIX not to check them, which has to be done in code by setting `[Session].CheckLatency = false`.

Comment: thank you for your help.problem got solved.actually the error was in source code.thank you so much.