# QuickFIXn - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: quickfix, quickfixn

I already checked [this existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267010/quickfix-n-erroran-existing-was-forcibly-closed-the-remote-host-at-quickfix-so), but it wasn't within my context. My FIX connection with FIX broker was setup since last 7 days and working properly, i was getting Market Data for my request to market data requests.

But all of the sudden since yesterday morning i am getting following error. I tried setting `CheckLatency=Y` or `CheckLatency=N` but still same result.

Error message -

> -02:36:35.627 : Session **FIX.4.2**:Edited-Sender-Sender-Comp-ID->Edited-target-comp-ID already disconnected: Resetting...
>
> 20180504-02:36:35.658 : Session reset: New session
>
> 20180504-02:36:37.705 : Created session
>
> 20180504-02:36:37.721 : Connecting to 114.144.100.10 on port 11111
>
> 20180504-02:36:37.846 : Connection succeeded
>
> 20180504-02:36:43.640 : Initiated logon request
>
> 20180504-02:36:43.765 : Session FIX.4.2:Edited-Sender-Sender-Comp-ID->Edited-target-comp-ID disconnecting: **System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host**
>      at QuickFix.SocketInitiatorThread.ReadSome(Byte[] buffer, Int32 timeoutMilliseconds)
>      at QuickFix.SocketInitiatorThread.Read()

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who faced this issue here is short answer.

Already another FIX Client connection was setup by another fellow (which he was not even aware of), After spending bit more time and stopping his connection this problem is fixed.

After all FIX Broker allows single FIX connection!